# How to send and receive multipart/form-data containing files in .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, http, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Using .NET Core 3.1, I have the following Http client which builds a HTTP POST containing multipart/form-data body:

```c#
public async Task SendRequest(string randomString, IFormFileCollection files) 
{
    var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    
    form.Add(new StringContent(randomString), "randomString");
    
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream, cancellationToken);
        form.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "files");
    }

    using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"api/endpoint")
    {
        Content = form
    };

    await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
}
```

The receiving controller looks like this:

```c#
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task ReceiveForm([FromForm] RequestModel request)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

`RequestModel` looks like this:

```c#
public class RequestModel 
{
    [JsonPropertyName("randomString")]
    public string RandomString { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("files")]
    public IFormFileCollection Files { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I am seeing is that `requestModel.RandomString` gets populated, but the `requestModel.Files` does not - it is null.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for the perfect code in example!

You should *set both parameters (name and fileName)* to **files** - `form.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "files", "files");`

Method description:

> Parameters:
> content: The HTTP content to add to the collection.
> name: The name for the HTTP content to add.
> fileName: The file name for the HTTP content to add to the collection.

This is my example:

```
var fileName = "files";
var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes1);
form.Add(byteArrayContent, fileName, fileName);

var stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes2);
form.Add(new StreamContent(stream), fileName, fileName);
```

Results:
[image: Results]

Comment: Adding a file name worked! Thank you!

Comment: No problem :) Also thank you for a good example